# How do I look up Active Directory from powershell with multiple variables?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

```
$ADInfo = Get-ADUser -filter {Surname -Like $ntaccount1} | Sort-Object Name

$ADInfo `
    | Format-Table `
        @{ Name = "Full Name"; Expression = { $_.name } },
        @{ Name = "User ID"; Expression = { $_.samaccountname } } -Autosize;
```

This will only search the Directory by Surname (Last name) and then it outputs the full name and user id of the results. How do I have it look for every variable instead of just Surname? I want to mimic as if you were searching in the actual active directory program, but in powershell.

Comment: You would need to change your `Filter` to account for all the variances you are looking for. Might be able to use a small hashtable to make it easier. Someone might have a better solution.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "every variable"?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Searching AD for the word "smith" but instead of searching last name, look in first name, user id, etc etc.

Comment: User objects in AD have more than 200 attributes. Which of them do you want to check?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Mainly last name, user id, first name. I just want a way to search multiple variables and display results from all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into other ideas but just to see if this is in the direction you are looking for I made up and LDAP filter for what I think the AD Find does

```
$searchString = "Matt"
get-aduser -LDAPFilter "(|(displayName=$($searchString)*)(sn=$($searchString)*)(givenName=$($searchString)*)(cn=$($searchString)*)(samaccountname=$($searchString)*))"
```

So this will search all of the properties in AD and return users if they match "Matt*". Following the same logic but making the seach more configurable to suit your needs. Results should be the same for both as written. This way you can add/remove properties to search for.

```
$searchString = "Matt"
$properties = "displayName","sn","givenName","cn","samaccountname"
$ldapFilter = "(|$($properties | ForEach-Object{"($_=$($searchString)*)"}))"

Get-Aduser -LDAPFilter $ldapFilter
```

**Using Plain Filter**

For whatever reason `-LDAPFilter` is not working for you. We can use similar logic to get `-Filter` working. The property names will change to match the PowerShell Filter

```
$searchString = "Matt"
$properties = "FirstName","LastName","Name","DisplayName","SamAccountName"
$Filter = ($properties | ForEach-Object{"($_ -Like '$searchString*')"}) -Join " -Or "

Get-Aduser -Filter $Filter
```

Comment: Does -LDAPFilter use LDAP? We are ditching LDAP soon for AD fully. I trie to do Get-ADUser -filter {samaccountname -Contains "stepanik"} but it says the operator of -contains is not valid. That would be perfect if that worked.

Comment: `-LDAPFilter` uses the LDAP protocol which is support on a wide variety of products. Yes this work on AD. My environment is AD Functional level 2008 r2

Comment: `-Contains` is for checking arrays contain a member. http://windowsitpro.com/blog/powershell-contains. I will make this work for `-Filter`

Comment: I know this is bad but, is there a way to paste all that code into powershell with the variables in one line to test it? or how do I go about doing that?

Comment: @Aaron copy the code from the page and just hit rightclick in the shell. It will paste it all and execute assuming you have a newline on the end. You could also separate the lines with semicolons if you really need it all on one line.